# Python Web App Using Flask, "app not defined" on Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, flask, flask-login

I am trying to run a simple app on heroku, however for some reason which I do not fully understand, app is not being defined by the code below when I push and try to run on heroku. When I run this code locally, it works fine using `python myApp.py`. I get "app is not defined". It seems I need to declare `app = Flask(__name__)` outside of the create app method. I got this code from the flask-user documentation. How can I get it to work so I can define app within the create_app method so that runs with heroku?

Requirements that I have are as follows, which may not all be used here:

```
['babel==2.2.0', 'bcrypt==2.0.0', 'blinker==1.4', 'cffi==1.5.0', 'flask-babel==0.9',
 'flask-login==0.3.2', 'flask-mail==0.9.1', 'flask-sqlalchemy==2.1', 'flask-user==0.6.8',
 'flask-wtf==0.12', 'flask==0.10.1', 'gunicorn==19.4.1', 'itsdangerous==0.24', 
'jinja2==2.8', 'markupsafe==0.23', 'mysql-python==1.2.5', 'mysql==0.0.1', 
'passlib==1.6.5', 'pip==7.1.2', 'pycparser==2.14', 'pycrypto==2.6.1', 
'pymysql==0.7.1', 'pytz==2015.7', 'setuptools==18.3.1', 'six==1.10.0', 
'speaklater==1.3', 'sqlalchemy==1.0.11', 'vboxapi==1.0', 'virtualenv==13.1.2', 
'werkzeug==0.11.3', 'wheel==0.24.0', 'wtforms==2.1']
```

---

```
 import os
    from flask import Flask, redirect, render_template_string, request, url_for
    from flask_babel import Babel
    from flask_mail import Mail
    from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
    from flask_user import confirm_email_required, current_user, login_required, UserManager, UserMixin, SQLAlchemyAdapter




# Use a Class-based config to avoid needing a 2nd file
# os.getenv() enables configuration through OS environment variables
class ConfigClass(object):
  ....


def create_app(test_config=None):                   # For automated tests
    # Setup Flask and read config from ConfigClass defined above
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(__name__+'.ConfigClass')

    # Load local_settings.py if file exists         # For automated tests
    try: app.config.from_object('local_settings')
    except: pass

    # Load optional test_config                     # For automated tests
    if test_config:
        app.config.update(test_config)

    # Initialize Flask extensions
    mail = Mail(app)                                # Initialize Flask-Mail
    db = SQLAlchemy(app)                            # Initialize Flask-SQLAlchemy

    # Define the User data model. Make sure to add flask.ext.user UserMixin!!
    class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
     ....

    # Define the Role data model
    class Role(db.Model):
    ....


    # Define the UserRoles data model
    class UserRoles(db.Model):
      ....


    db_adapter = SQLAlchemyAdapter(db,  User)
    user_manager = UserManager(db_adapter, app)


    @app.route('/')
    def home_page():
        return render_template_string(....)


    return app

# Start development web server
if __name__=='__main__':
    app = create_app()
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080, debug=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku does not run this code at the bottom:

```
# Start development web server
if __name__=='__main__':
    app = create_app()
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080, debug=True)
```

It runs the code you have given in your procfile. You should execute the `create_app` method in your procfile, like the following. You will need to escape the parenthesis.

`web: gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:$PORT app:create_app\(\)`

Also FYI: You can test what heroku will do by installing the Heroku Toolbelt and running `heroku local` in your application directory.

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate your answer. That makes sense. I had "main:app" running the procfile and didn't realize that.